# SBT dependencies

Tags: scala, sbt

Trying to download the SBT dependencies behind the proxy from a nexus repository. Getting the below error message.

```
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: download failed: org.scala-    sbt#main;0.13.13!main.jar
[error] download failed: org.scala-sbt#actions;0.13.13!actions.jar
[error] download failed: org.scala-sbt#io;0.13.13!io.jar
[error] download failed: org.scala-sbt#completion;0.13.13!completion.jar
[error] download failed: org.scala-sbt#collections;0.13.13!collections.jar
[error] download failed: org.scala-sbt#api;0.13.13!api.jar
[error] download failed: org.scala-sbt#incremental-compiler;0.13.13!incremental-compiler.jar
[error] download failed: org.scala-sbt#compile;0.13.13!compile.jar
[error] download failed: org.scala-sbt#ivy;0.13.13!ivy.jar
[error] download failed: org.scala-sbt#main-settings;0.13.13!main-settings.jar
[error] download failed: org.scala-sbt#command;0.13.13!command.jar
[error] download failed: org.scala-sbt#compiler-interface;0.13.13!compiler-interface.jar
```

Comment: Do you have proxy values setup in your environment?? (Are you using linux or windows?) You also can set it up using `JAVA_OPTS` like `export JAVA_OPTS = "-Dhttp.proxyHost=x.y.z.a .....`

Comment: I am using windows 7. I am connecting to nexus repo using SBT. Repository has  http://companynexus/nexus/content/groups/reponame/. This repo is having access to internet typesafe ivy , maven , sonatype repos etc.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how nexus communicates to mvnrepository.com etc? Generally I used to setup my proxy as `-Dhttp.proxyHost=myproxyserver -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttp.proxyUser=username -Dhttp.proxyPassword=secret` when I had to download dependencies behind proxy. (without nexus in between). If you know the proxy values(`host:port`, `username`, `password`) I would recommend it.

Comment: In which file of the project should we specify the configurations. My project is using scala and Akka . Should we configure in build.sbt file ?

Comment: No you have to configure on sbtconfig file, which would be in `sbt_installed_directory/conf/sbtconfig.txt`. Let me know if you find that. I assume you are using sbt from windows command prompt like `C:\your_project>sbt compile`

Comment: Yup able to find the file in the installation directory . Yes i am using sbt from windows command promt.

Comment: Alrighty! Try adding the proxy configs to the `sbtconfig.txt` and run `sbt clean compile`. Hope that works